# Proof of Monotone Convergence Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory

I am currently studying the proof of Monotone convergence theorem for Lebesgue measurable functions and I have a doubt about the proof. In the book from Ash *Probability and Measure Theroy* they make use of a simple positive finite-valued function to prove that

$\lim_{n} \int f_n d\mu \ge \int \lim_n f_n d\mu$

In fact, they say that letting $s<f$ with s simple and f the limit of the sequence, we can take $0 \lt b \lt 1 $ and

$B_n=\{\omega : f_n (\omega) \ge bs(\omega)\} \uparrow \Omega$

one can say

$\int f_n d\mu \ge \int_{B_n} f_n d\mu \ge b\int_{B_n} s d\mu$

and taking the limits on both sides and letting $b \rightarrow 1$ yields the result.

My question is: why use the simple function? Could one directly use the limit function f to prove the statement?  Like for example letting

$B_n = \{\omega : f_n (\omega) \ge (1- \varepsilon) f(\omega)\}$

for given $\varepsilon$

$\int f_n d\mu \ge \int_{B_n} f_n d\mu \ge (1-\varepsilon)\int_{B_n} f d\mu$

and since $\varepsilon$ is arbitrary we can say

$\int f_n d\mu \ge \int_{B_n} f d\mu$

Taking limits on both sides would yield the result.

Is there something wrong in the statements I made? Why Ash uses the simple function instead of the limit function?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You write $B_n$ but shouldn't that be $B_{n,\epsilon}$?

Comment: How do you know that $\lim_n\int_{B_n}f\,d\mu=\int f\,d\mu$? For *simple* $s$, the analogous fact is seen by explicit calculation using the fact that $\lim_n\mu(A\cap B_n)=\mu(A)$ for each measurable $A$.

Comment: In a previous theorem it was stated that $\int f d\mu$ is a measure when f is nonnegative, so I assumed that the limit above is just the measure of the limit which is in fact Omega.

Comment: drhab, assuming $\varepsilon$ arbitrary, the sets shouldn't depend on it, right?

Comment: the set $\{f_n\geq(1-\epsilon)f\}$ is evidently a set that depends on $\epsilon$. You disregard that by calling it $B_n$. If you let $\epsilon\to0$ to come to your "result" $\int f_nd\mu\geq\int_{B_n}fd\mu$ then also the set that you called $B_n$ will get smaller.

Comment: Why does the same not apply to the set $\{f_n \ge bs \}$? That should depend on b too, right? Furthermore, I don't see how this invalidate the proof.

Comment: In the proof in the book they first let $n\to\infty$ (this with a fixed $b$) and secondly they let $b\uparrow1$. That's why it is irrelevant there to write $B_{n,b}$ instead of $B_n$. You are doing it the other way arround: first $\epsilon\downarrow0$ and after that $n\to\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

If for $\epsilon>0$ we define $B_{n,\epsilon}:=\{f_n\geq(1-\epsilon)f\}$ then indeed we have $\int f_n\geq(1-\epsilon)\int_{B_{n,\epsilon}} f$.

From this however we cannot conclude that also $\int f_n\geq\int_{B_{n,\epsilon}}f$ under argumentation that $\epsilon$ is "arbitrary".

Look e.g. what happens if we let $(\epsilon_k)_k$ be a sequence with $\epsilon_k\downarrow0$. Then we can observe that: $$\forall k\left[\int f_n\geq(1-\epsilon_k)\int_{B_{n,\epsilon_k}} f\right]$$

In that situation $B_{n,\epsilon_k}\downarrow\{f_n\geq f\}$.

So by an $\epsilon$ that gets smaller we at most find that  $\int f_n\geq\int_{\{f_n\geq f\}}f$ which we allready knew.

Nothing is gained.

Comment: So if I first let $n \rightarrow \infty$ I'd obtain $lim_n \int f_n d\mu \ge (1-\varepsilon) \int f d\mu$ and then $\varepsilon \downarrow 0$, would it be correct?

Comment: On what do you base that RHS converges to $(1-\epsilon)\int f$ if $n\to\infty$ ?

Comment: From the fact that $\lambda (A) = \int_A f d\mu$ is a measure, and since $B_n \uparrow \Omega$ we get $\lambda (B_n) \rightarrow \lambda (\Omega )$ which means $\int_{B_n} f d\mu \rightarrow \int f d\mu$

Comment: Then actually you base it on $f1_{B_n}\uparrow f\implies \int f1_{B_n}\uparrow \int f$. So you use MCS in order to prove MCS. This is strictly forbidden of course.

Comment: If you go the route of proving that $A\mapsto\int_Af$ then you will encounter usance of MCS.  So it cannot be used to prove MCS afterwards.

Comment: You sure? In Ash the fact that $\int_A f d\mu$ is a measure is proven before and independently from MCT (Theorem 1.6.1 of the book, MCT is 1.6.2) and then I'm just applying continuity of measures wrt Monotone sequences of sets.

Comment: I am not completely sure. If it can be done without then this might be a way to prove MCT after all. By bringing in measures it can be reduced to proving that $B_n\uparrow B$ implies  $mB_n\uparrow mB$